# Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br/> Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to showing this value to listview on flutter

```
[{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"13,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"130,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"13,000,000.00","Installment":"13,130,000.00","Status":true}]
```

but i get the result like

```
I/flutter (12074): Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (12074): <br />
I/flutter (12074): ^
I/flutter (12074):
```

here is my List LoanModel

```
static Future<List<LoanModel>> getsimulation({String periodtime, String interestpermonth, String loanamountrequest, String idUser, String url}) async  {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=" + periodtime + "&interestpermonth=" + interestpermonth + "&loanamountrequest=" +loanamountrequest;
    final response = await http.get(url,headers:{"Content-Type":
    "application/json"});
    var res = LoanModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
    print(response.body);
  }
```

here is the function to load JSON when already input value periodtime, interestpermonth and loanamountrequest

```
_load() async {
    List<LoanModel> loanmodel =
    (await RestApi.getsimulation());
    setState(() => _loanmodel = loanmodel);
  }
```

Here is my Model

```
List<LoanModel> allLoan(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return new List<LoanModel>.from(jsonData.map((x) => LoanModel.fromJson(x)));
}

class LoanModel {
  bool Status;
  String message;
  String No;
  String interest;
  String balance;
  String principal;
  String Installment;
  List<Data> data;

  LoanModel({
    this.Status,
    this.message,
    this.No,
    this.interest,
    this.balance,
    this.principal,
    this.Installment,
    this.data,
  });

  factory LoanModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var list = parsedJson['data'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);
    List<Data> dataList = list.map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return LoanModel(
      Status: parsedJson['Status'],
      message: parsedJson['message'],
      No : parsedJson['No'],
      interest: parsedJson['interest'],
      balance: parsedJson['balance'],
      principal: parsedJson['principal'],
      Installment: parsedJson['Installment'],
      data: dataList,
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  final int No;
  final String interest;
  final String balance;
  final String principal;
  final String Installment;

  Data({
    this.No,
    this.interest,
    this.balance,
    this.principal,
    this.Installment
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Data(
      No: parsedJson['No'],
      interest: parsedJson['interest'],
      balance: parsedJson['balance'],
      principal: parsedJson['principal'],
      Installment: parsedJson['Installment']
    );
  }
```

and the result is keep loading like this
[image]

The output should be like this
[image]

How can i make output like picture number 2 and how to resolved this Unexpected character in flutter?
thank you

Comment: I would say you got an HTTP response code that wasn't 200, and was accompanied by an HTML error page. Check the response code before you try to parse the response as JSON.

Comment: In postman, API is working properly. Any Suggestion for this?

Comment: result is 200 but it return Error

Comment: I/flutter (12439): true
I/flutter (12439): 200
I/flutter (12439): Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (12439): <br />

Comment: Well you will have to print out what you actually received before you try to parse it, to see what is being sent to you. The error appears to be at the other end, sending HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: Try save "loansimulation.php" without bom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to parse it with the JSON locally. Update the dataModel:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<LoanModel> loanModelFromJson(String str) => List<LoanModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => LoanModel.fromJson(x)));

String loanModelToJson(List<LoanModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class LoanModel {
    LoanModel({
        this.no,
        this.interest,
        this.balance,
        this.principal,
        this.installment,
        this.status,
    });

    int no;
    String interest;
    String balance;
    String principal;
    String installment;
    bool status;

    factory LoanModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoanModel(
        no: json["No"],
        interest: json["interest"],
        balance: json["balance"],
        principal: json["principal"],
        installment: json["Installment"],
        status: json["Status"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "No": no,
        "interest": interest,
        "balance": balance,
        "principal": principal,
        "Installment": installment,
        "Status": status,
    };
}
```

Any try to parse it like this:

```
arr = loanModelFromJson(response.body);
```

RestAPI call

```
class APIManager {
  final String baseURL = [BaseURL];

  getData(apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = baseURL + apiUrl;
    return await http.get(Uri.parse(fullUrl), headers: _setHeader());
  }
}

  Future<void> getData() async {
    var response = await APIManager().getData([Endpoint]);
    arr = loanModelFromJson(response.body);
  }
```